# patsubst did not translate *.c to *.o

Tags: makefile

My test project folder structure looks like:

```
TOPDIR
├── a
│   └── a.c
├── b
│   └── b.c
├── c
│   └── c.mk
└── makefile
```

I wrote a test `makefile`:

```
MAKE_DIR = $(PWD)
MODULES   := a b c
SRC_DIR   := $(addprefix ${MAKE_DIR}/,$(MODULES))
BUILD_DIR := $(addprefix ${MAKE_DIR}/build/,$(MODULES))

SRC       := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(wildcard $(sdir)/*.c))
OBJ       := $(patsubst ${SRC_DIR}/%.c,${BUILD_DIR}/%.o,$(SRC))
INCLUDES  := $(addprefix -I,$(SRC_DIR))

vpath %.c $(SRC_DIR)

default:
    @echo "SRC DIR:    ${SRC_DIR}"
    @echo "Build DIR:  ${BUILD_DIR}"
    @echo "Source:     ${SRC}"
    @echo "Obj:        ${OBJ}"
    @echo "Includes:   ${INCLUDES}"
```

and it output:

```
[GNU-GCC]howchen@linux:~/Work/c/c/test/test_make
-> make
SRC DIR:    /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/a /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/b /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/c
Build DIR:  /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/a /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/b /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/c
Source:     /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/a/a.c /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/b/b.c /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/c/c.c
Obj:        /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/a/a.c /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/b/b.c /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/c/c.c
Includes:   -I/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/a -I/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/b -I/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/c
```

The `${Obj}` variables are NOT on `*.o` format, why? any problem in my `makefile`?

**UPDATE**

regarding Magnus Reftel's help, I first try:

```
OBJ := $(foreach sdir,$(SRC_DIR),$(patsubst $(sdir)/%.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o,$(filter $(sdir)/%.c,$(SRC))))
```

and it output like:

```
Obj: 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/a
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/b 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/c/a.o 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/a 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/b 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/c/b.o 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/a 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/b 
/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/build/c/c.o
```

The output contain both `PATH` and `PATH/*.c` these two things, seems still NOT correct because ALL obj files go to folder `c` ONLY

I think I already got the source file list, which stored in `$(SRC)`, therefore I try:

```
OBJ := $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(SRC))
```

and it output:

```
Obj: /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/a/a.o /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/b/b.o /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/c/c.o
```

which seems correct, but not because I need locate the output obj file in my build folder not source folder.

- If my first try statement is not correct, where is the problem?
- If second way can be improved? which way to get `$(OBJ)` is best for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `SRC_DIR` holds a list of directories, not just one. The pattern you're matching is therefore `/home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/a /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/b /home/howchen/Work/c/c/test/test_make/c/%.c` which is surely not what you want. Try combining `patsubst` with the `foreach` function. Something along the lines of

```
OBJ       := $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIR),$(patsubst $(dir)/%.c,getting/the/correct/build/dir/here/is/left/as/an/excercise/to/the/reader%.o,$(filter $(dir)/%,$(SRC))))
```

Comment: I try your way but I have new problem and I update my new result in my question

Comment: Hm, you filter on `$(dir)/%.`c, but the `foreach` variable is named `sdir`. Could that be it?

Comment: I made typo, it should be `sdir` in filter, but still problem

Comment: Same problem as with `SRC_DIR`: `BUILD_DIR` holds a list of directories. You only want the one that matches your particular `sdir`. They way I tend to do it is to have `a_SRC` and `a_BUILD` and then do `$(foreach module,$(MODULES),$(patsubst $($(module)_SRC)/%.c,$($(module)_BUILD)/%.o,$($(module)_FILES)))` or similar.

Comment: @MagnusReftel I have a question regarding the necessity of filter. I had a similar rule (producing an error) that instead of `filter` had only `$(SRC)`. Why is `filter` needed here? Shouldn't `patsubst` match only the elements of `$(SRC)` that contain `$(dir)`?

Comment: It´s been seven years, so I´m a bit hazy, but I _think_ it is because otherwise, things in `SRC` that are not in the `SRC_DIR` directory that is currently in `dir` would be passed though unmodified. `patsubst` will replace the first occurrence of the pattern in the text, but for text that does not contain the pattern, that text is returned unmodified.