# Order of targets in Makefile when rule created by eval

Tags: linux, makefile

I wrote a Makefile which uses a similar idea to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324073/function-define-in-makefile). That is, I define a set of directories and using `foreach` and `define` I build all objects in each one of the directories. Here how my Makefile looks roughly

```
all_dirs := $(shell ...) # long shell command which finds all directories
all_objs := $(shell ...) # long shell command which finds all objects

define compile_rule
$(BUILDDIR)/$(1)/%.o :  $(1)/%.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)
endef

$(foreach dir,$(all_dirs:$(BUILDDIR)/%=%),$(eval $(call compile_rule,$(dir))))

all : program_name

program_name: $(all_objs)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(all_objs) $(LDFLAGS)
```

I always run the `make` command with `-j32` argument. Usually it works fine but in some cases I get an error from the Makefile it self saying `No rule to make target` with the first object file name in `$(all_objs)` list `needed by program_name`.

Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647480/in-what-order-prerequisites-will-be-made-by-the-gnu-make) the problem is clear. Since I'm using `-j` it seems like the make command starts to evaluate `program_name` before it expands the rules created by `foreach`. I tried to write the `foreach` inside a rule so I could guarantee the order of execution between `program_name` and the `foreach` but then I got the error `prerequisites cannot be defined in recipes`.

Any idea how to solve this? I might be able to solve this using a two step make, that is by first building `$(all_objs)` with something like `make objs` and then linking them together with something like `make prog` but I prefer it will all happen in one command and I have a feeling I miss something simple. Please advise.

Comment: If using GNU make 4, you could use its Guile scriptability feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work, but I haven't tested it:

```
# ...

prereq: $(foreach dir ...)

program_name: $(all_objs) | prereq
  $(LD) ...
```

It *seems* to work on my test setup, but I've only tested with a few directories and objects. The pipe is an [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types), and it looks like it's OK to put the for-loop in a target.

**Suggestion**

If you really want to, you can download the [GNU Make 3.82 source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/), apply the patch below with `patch < function.c.patch` and then invoke make with `make --debug=b -j32 ...` and watch for `Call`, `Evaluating` and `Executing` lines.

```
--- function.c  2010-07-13 03:20:39.000000000 +0200
+++ function.c.patched  2015-04-18 20:41:15.000000000 +0200
@@ -1371,6 +1371,8 @@

   install_variable_buffer (&buf, &len);

+   DB (DB_BASIC, (_("Evaluating: %s\n"), argv[0]));
+
   eval_buffer (argv[0]);

   restore_variable_buffer (buf, len);
@@ -1652,6 +1654,11 @@
       return o;
     }

+   DB (DB_BASIC, (_("Executing shell command:")));
+  for ( char **p=command_argv; *p!=NULL; ++p )
+    DB (DB_BASIC, (_(" %s"), *p));
+  DB (DB_BASIC, (_("\n")));
+
 # ifdef __EMX__
   /* close some handles that are unnecessary for the child process */
   CLOSE_ON_EXEC(pipedes[1]);
@@ -2311,6 +2318,12 @@
     --cp;
   cp[1] = '\0';

+   DB (DB_BASIC, (_("Call %s:"), fname));
+  for ( char **p=argv; *p!=NULL; ++p )
+    DB (DB_BASIC, (_(" %s"), *p));
+  DB (DB_BASIC, (_("\n")));
+
+
   /* Calling nothing is a no-op */
   if (*fname == '\0')
     return o;
```

This way you can actually *see* if `call compile_rule` is run when it's not supposed to.  In my case, the output is:

```
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Reading makefiles...
Executing shell command: find . -type d
Call compile_rule: compile_rule .
Evaluating: ./%.foo: ./%.txt
    @echo build $@ from $<
Call compile_rule: compile_rule ./1
Evaluating: ./1/%.foo: ./1/%.txt
    @echo build $@ from $<
Call compile_rule: compile_rule ./2
Evaluating: ./2/%.foo: ./2/%.txt
    @echo build $@ from $<
Updating goal targets....
 File `program' does not exist.
   File `1/1.foo' does not exist.
  Must remake target `1/1.foo'.
Invoking recipe from Makefile:11 to update target `1/1.foo'.
   File `2/2.foo' does not exist.
  Must remake target `2/2.foo'.
Invoking recipe from Makefile:11 to update target `2/2.foo'.
   File `prereq' does not exist.
  Must remake target `prereq'.
  Successfully remade target file `prereq'.
build 1/1.foo from 1/1.txt
 File `program' does not exist.
build 2/2.foo from 2/2.txt
 File `program' does not exist.
Must remake target `program'.
Invoking recipe from Makefile:9 to update target `program'.
link program w/args 1/1.foo 2/2.foo
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same issue exists. When you say it worked for you I believe you, it also works for me, but not always. I compile my program on AWS EC2 service, most of the time the instance is shut down. When I want to compile I have a python script (using [boto](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)) which turns on the instance and runs the `make -j32` command. At the first compilation when the instance is turned on, this problem reproduces almost every time. Please let me know if you have a better idea.

Comment: Which version of GNU make do you use?

Comment: Try running the make command with the `-d` flag. It should print a lot of debugging info which could perhaps be used to see why this is happening.

Comment: So `-d` plus redirecting the output to a file solved the issue (indirectly) I guess cause the time that it takes for the debug info be written to file allows the Makefile to resolve all rules. This is of course not the solution I was looking for but it certainly helped :-) and eventually I do appreciate the time you found to let me know your opinion about my Makefile problems.

Comment: As a last comment I'd like to say that this problem reproduces mainly (but not only) when the system starts up. I guess some conditions are met at start up which create this problem more easily then in the rest of the system up time. However, after a week of looking into this issue, I admit I'm clueless. The only true solution I can think of to write all the rules explicitly.

Comment: Ok, this sounds more like an issue that should be posted on the GNU makefile lists? Maybe it's a known issue, or a bug?