# Makefile: Declaring dependencies between included files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Using make's ''Remaking Makefiles'' feature I am generating parts of my makefile with `include` directives (see [Makefile: defining rules and prerequisites in recipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188323/)). Now I'm stuck with being unable to see how I can express dependencies between included makefiles. They seem to be all evaluated at once.

Consider the following minimal makefile that illustrates my problem:

```
all:

-include foo.make
-include bar.make

foo.make: Makefile
    echo FOO:=blub bla baz > foo.make

bar.make: Makefile foo.make
    echo BAR:=$(FOO) > bar.make
```

If I now run `make` I will get:

```
$ cat foo.make
FOO:=blub bla baz
$ cat bar.make
BAR:=
```

Why? Since `bar.make` depends on `foo.make`, shouldn't the evaluation of `bar.make` wait until it successfully included `foo.make`?

And how do I fix this problem and make sure that `bar.make` is either re-evaluated later or only evaluated once `foo.make` exists, is included and can define the variable `BAR`?

The reason I cannot combine `foo.make` and `bar.make` into a single makefile and rule is two-fold:

Firstly, in my real setup, `bar.make` depends on more intermediate targets which in turn transitively depend on `foo.make`. So at the time `foo.make` can be created, the content of `bar.make` cannot yet be made.

Secondly, in my real setup, `foo.make` and `bar.make` do not just define variables but also `eval()` `define/endef` blocks. So I have to write:

```
-include makefile_with_prerequisite_variables
define MYDEF
sometarget-$1: $(TARGET_$1_PREREQUISITES)
    [...]
endf
-include makefile_with_eval_call_statements
```

The content of `makefile_with_prerequisite_variables` and `makefile_with_eval_call_statements` cannot go into a single makefile snippet:

- If I would put `makefile_with_eval_call_statements` *above* `MYDEF` together with `makefile_with_prerequisite_variables` then the `$eval( $call( MYDEF))` statements in it would not work because `MYDEF` is only declared *afterward*.
- If I would put `makefile_with_prerequisite_variables` *below* `MYDEF` together with `makefile_with_eval_call_statements` then the recipes defined in `MYDEF` would not have proper prerequisits because the `$(TARGET_$1_PREREQUISITES)` variables would then be declared *afterward* by `makefile_with_prerequisite_variables`.

In summary, I need to include two different makefiles where one depends upon the other. I do not know how I can express this relationship such that the content of one makefile would only be created after the other makefile is up-to-date and included into the main makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your makefile creation in this simple example can easily be fixed by escaping the value of `$(FOO)` so that it's not expanded when `bar.make` is created but rather deferred until it's read in.  So:

```
bar.make: Makefile foo.make
        echo 'BAR:=$$(FOO)' > $@
```

However, that might not be sufficient in your more complex real-life makefiles.

GNU make works like this: first parse all the makefiles.  Then for every included makefile, treat it as a goal and try to build it (e.g., act as if the user invoked `make include1.mk include2.mk include3.mk ...`).  Then at the end of that, if any of the included makefiles was rebuilt, re-exec ourselves and start the entire process over from scratch.

GNU make does *NOT* work like this: parse makefiles, try to rebuild the first included makefile and if it's rebuilt, re-exec; if it's not rebuilt go on to the next included makefile, etc.

A simple trick you can use if you have to have this type of order is to put the include of `bar.make` into `foo.make`:

```
all:

-include foo.make

foo.make: Makefile
        printf -- '-include bar.make' > $@
        echo FOO:=blub bla baz >> $@

bar.make: Makefile foo.make
        echo 'BAR:=$$(FOO)' > $@
```

By doing this you ensure that if `foo.make` doesn't exist, make can't see the include of `bar.make` and so it won't try to build it.  Only after the first re-exec will make see the include of `bar.make` and try to build it.

One thing: if you get the latest version of GNU make you no longer need to use the `-include` trick.  You can just use `include` even with generated makefiles.

Comment: You saved my day yet again! If I could give you more upvotes I would. Both of your suggestions are very valuable. Thanks a lot!